# What's the best way to make object aware of his place in a list?

Tags: c#, list

I have an object, that is saved in a certain list. However, the object itself should be aware of the fact that he's in a list and has neighbours in this list. Other entities working with this object, while they don't have to know about the whole list, still need to know about the object's neighbours and even be notified when the object's neighbours change.

A simple example would be of keeping the list of images and displaying it on the screen with buttons "Previous" and "Next" alongside it, while the source list changes in background on it's own accord.

Let's say, for this example, that I have something like this:

```
public class ImageListController
{
    private List<Image> m_ImageList = new List<Image>();

    // ... some code changing the list

}

public class ImageView
{
    // ...
    private Image m_Image;
    private Button m_Next;
    private Button m_Previous;

    void OnImageUpdate() // subscribed to events from m_Image
    {
        if (m_Image.Previous != null)
        {
            m_Previous.Enabled = true;
            m_Previous.Action = (System.Action) (() => DisplayImage(m_Image.Previous));
        }
        else
        {
            m_Previous.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

What's the best way to implement this?

(I can, of course, implement this myself from scratch, but I suspect that there's some kind of built-in collection type that already exists for that purpose.)

Comment: some code of what you currently have would be useful

Comment: @Tanner I can write down some example code, but how would it help this particular question?

Comment: Added example code, I hope it clears up what I'm trying to do here

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to make object aware of his place in a list?

Object shouldn't know whether it is inside the list, or array or field, or local. If same object is referenced in multiple places how'll you address that? It makes no sense for me.

It sounds like you're looking for [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you got the node, you can then use [Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4t9w6be%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Previous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de80z2x6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties to find its friends.

Comment: "If same object is referenced in multiple places how'll you address that?" I only need to know about his neighbours in a context of specific, special list. I thought about `LinkedList`, but `LinkedListNode` doesn't have events about changes in neighbour nodes.